# dashed line in between slick dots of slick slider

Tags: html, css, slider, slick.js

I want to create dashed line between slick dots of slick slider . I have uploaded image for it . How can I achieved this ?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CU6GE.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

I would use the setting `appendDots` to append the dots to a wrapping div that has the dashed line as a background.

Perhaps *something like* (**untested**):

```
 $('.slider').slick({
   slidesToShow: 3,
   slidesToScroll: 1,
   dots: true,
   appendDots: '.js-slick-dots',
 });
```

HTML

```
<div class="slick-dots-wrapper">
  <hr class="dotted-line">
  <div class="js-slick-dots"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.slide-dots-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.dotted-line {
  border-top: 1px dashed #fff;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}

.js-slick-dots {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 99;
}
```